# get tcp_info with netlink for all connections?

Tags: linux, tcp, netlink

Is it possible to get `TCP_INFO` struct with netlink for all tcp connections on linux? `NETLINK_SOCK_DIAG` seems doesn't contain that information

If not netlink, what other options do I have?